# Application logic and Active Record example Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to ask two things:

1) In the application logic of Rails , is correct to call a Model into another Model?
In other words:

```
class A
  def function1
   ...
  end
end

class B
  def function2
    A.function1
  end
end
```

This is just an example and there isn't any association  between the two Models.

The second question is:

2) When i call in the Rails console: c = Supply.where(product_id: 7)
i have this result

[image]

and i'm not able to call:  c.quantity

If i use c = Supply.find(1)
i can call c.quantity

[image]

What is the difference?

Thanks all

[image]

Comment: Your first question is pretty much incomprehensible. In your second question `Supply.where(product_id: 7)` gives an ActiveRecord::Relation which can represent many Supplies. `Supply.find(1)` gives a single `Supply` instance.

Comment: Hi , thank you for your answer. In the first question , i wanted to say if i respect the MVC logic , calling a method of a Model into another Model   (Call method of the Object A into a method of Object B). For the second question , if a want to take just one Supply, how i have to do?

Comment: MVC in the widest sense does not specify how your models interact - just that the application is structured into Models-Views-Controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to call a model into/from another model. It's common practice. As for the second question:

If you are querying by id always use find because it returns a single object and not a relation.

```
#this will work
c = Supply.find(7).quantity
```

If you use where you will need to pull a single object out of the result set. Example:

```
# this will work but since you are using where you need to ask for a specific object.
c = Supply.where(product_id: 7).first.quantity
```